# Получение списка Id людей вконтакте. Удаление через api

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как получить список Id людей, которые лайкнули вконтакте? И как удалить через api?
Я создал приложение вконтакте и поставил ссылку на него на сайте.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  VK.init({
    apiId: 5309489,
    onlyWidgets: true
  });
 VK.Widgets.Like('vk_like', {width: 500, pageTitle: 'Ukrtest.in.ua -сайт для подготовки к экзаменам  КРОК Онлайн', pageDescription: 'Ukrtest.in.ua -сайт для подготовки к экзаменам  КРОК Онлайн',type:'button'}, 0);
</script>
<div id="vk_like"></div>
```

**1.**  Есть ли способ через api узнать всех пользователей, которые лайкнули?
**2.**  Как можно удалить лайк человека(например, если он "заморожен" и мне собачки не нужны в лайках) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. https://vk.com/dev/likes.getList
2. Через API этого не сделать, но можно очистить через сайт.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Первое есть. И что-то странное во втором- у меня нет прав на блокировку. Приложение создал я. На сайте вывел кнопку от моего приложения. Почему-то я не могу удалить человека

Comment: @Rakzin Roman Могу предположить, что для удаления лайков можно блокировать юзеров через API и они будут автоматом удаляться.Но не факт